# Is $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p} \,/\, \mathbb{F}_p)$ cyclic?

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

I know if $L/K$ is a extension of finite fields then $\text{Gal}(L/K)=\langle \phi \rangle$ where $\phi:L\longrightarrow L$ is the Frobenius automorphism.

How can I show that it is also true for the extension $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}\,/ \,\mathbb{F}_p$? Because in this case $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is not a finite field.

Comment: $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb F_p}/\mathbb F_p)$ is isomorphic to the profinite completion $\hat{\mathbb Z}$ of the integers.

Comment: @Marktmeister do you know a reference?

Comment: As the other commenter remarked, it is isomorphic to $\hat \mathbb Z$ which is topologically generated by $1$ element, so it is ``almost'' cyclic in the sense that it has a dense subgroup which is cyclic. It cannot be just plain cyclic because, for instance, it isn't countable.

Comment: For infinite Galois extensions $L/K$, one has $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K) \cong \varprojlim \mathrm{Gal}(F/K)$, where the projective limit runs over all finite Galois extensions of $K$, see Serge Lang, Algebra, p. 313. Applied to the case in question, one has that the Galois group in question is isomorphic to $\varprojlim \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, which is just the profinite completion of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Marktmeister thank you very much

Comment: @TokenToucan thank you very much

Comment: Everything so far said is correct, lacks only the remark that a “pro-generator” is the Frobenius, which sends any element $\beta\in\overline{\Bbb F_p}$ to $\beta^p$.

Comment: @Lubin thank you

Comment: And here "almost cyclic" is officially "procyclic".